# Why am I not targeting the button in my div?

Tags: html, sass

I'm not sure why my button is not being animated properly. I think it has to do with targeting. I'm trying to target the button that is within my divs whenever I hover over the div:

```css
.homePageDiv:hover>.homePageButton {
  animation: pulsingButton 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes pulsingButton {
  0%,
  50%,
  100% {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
  }
  25% {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
  }
  75% {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="aboutMeDiv" class="homePageDiv">
  <button id="aboutMeBtn" class="homePageButton">
   <span id = "aboutMe">About Me</span>
  </button>
</div>

<div id="notesDiv" class="homePageDiv">
  <button id="notesBtn" class="homePageButton">
   <span id = "notes">Notes</span>
  </button>
</div>

<div id="projectsDiv" class="homePageDiv">
  <button id="projectsBtn" class="homePageButton">
   <span id = "projects">Projects</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I converted your code into a live demo, there doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: It works for me. When my mouse cursor is horizontally next to a button, that button animates. What is wrong with what you are seeing?

Comment: You want it to animate only when you hover over the button ?

Comment: Ah i figured out the issue, and it's not related. Thank you for informing me that it worked for you all. It was not working because I had a different animation already occurring on the button before hand. I will need to learn how to have multiple animations. I suppose then that someone can take this question down.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by moving my other animation to my div, so this animation was then able to function on the button, so I didn't really have to change much, either way this question is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.homePageDiv:hover>.homePageButton {
    animation: pulsingButton 2s linear infinite;
  }
  .homePageDiv {
    display: inline;
  }
  
  @keyframes pulsingButton {
    0%,
    50%,
    100% {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
    }
    25% {
      height: 150px;
      width: 150px;
    }
    75% {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div id="aboutMeDiv" class="homePageDiv">
        <button id="aboutMeBtn" class="homePageButton">
                  <span id = "aboutMe">About Me</span>
              </button>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="notesDiv" class="homePageDiv">
        <button id="notesBtn" class="homePageButton">
                  <span id = "notes">Notes</span>
              </button>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="projectsDiv" class="homePageDiv">
        <button id="projectsBtn" class="homePageButton">
                  <span id = "projects">Projects</span>
              </button>
      </div>
```